# Prove properties of $e^A$ when $A$ is a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and define $e^A = I + A + \frac{A^2}{2!} + \ldots = \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}$, $A$ is non-singular matrix.

- Show $\int e^{At}Adt=e^{At}$ and $\frac{d}{dt}(e^{At})=Ae^{At}$,
- Prove $\lim \limits_{t\to\infty} e^{-A^TAt} = 0$ then conclude $A^\dagger = \int \limits_0^\infty e^{-A^TAt} Adt $, where $A^\dagger$ is pseudo-inverse of $A$.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  For the first one you use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @mathematician second part. one hint maybe useful.

Comment: I see that $A$ is square. Are there any other assumptions? Is it linearly independent/diagonalizable?

Comment: The second statement, as it stands, is wrong. As a counterexample, take $A$ to be the zero matrix.

Comment: @Rellek yes, sorry I forget to mention $A$ is a pseudo-invertible. Since $A$ is square, then is's invertible.

Comment: @yohBS thanks, $A$ is invertible matrix.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT 1**:

$B=A^TA$ is a symmetric matrix.

As such, it can be diagonalized by a unitary congruence as $U^TBU=\Lambda$, where $U^TU=I$ and $\Lambda$ is diagonal with elements equal to the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, $(i=1, 2, \cdots , n)$, of $B$.  That is $(U^TBU)_{ij}=\lambda_i\,\delta_{ij}$

**HINT 2**:

$e^{-Bt}=(UU^T)e^{-Bt}(U^TU)=(UU^T)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^nB^n}{n!}(UU^T)$

and $U^TB^nU=U^TB(UU^T)B(UU^T)\cdots B(UU^T)BU=(U^TBU)^n \Lambda^n$ is a diagonal matrix.